# How to get words timestamps using speech_recognition in Python?

Tags: python, timestamp, signal-processing, speech-recognition, speech

I want to determine, when exactly a speech in the audio file starts and ends. Firstly, I am using speech_recognition library to determine speech content of the audio file:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 

filename = './dir_name/1.wav'
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:

    audio_data = r.record(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language = "en-US")
    print(text)
```

Running this code I get a correct output (speech recognized content of the audio file). How can I determine, where exactly the speech starts and ends? Let's assume the file contains ONLY speech. I tried different methods, e. g. by analysing amplitude of the signal, its envelope etc. but I do not get high efficiency. So I started using speech_recognition library with a hope it could be useful here.